# Url masking with domains in different server

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting, dns, masking

I have domain.com and redirected it to domain2.com (which is in a different server) with .htaccess. but masking seams to be little difficult as they a re in different servers . How to do the domain masking . Any possible way to do that (may be php, .htaccess or anything else) .
I bought hosting for domain.com from a private domain register.

Comment: I don't believe this is possible with .htaccess - try using the DNS records. Make domain.com point to domain2.com with a CNAME or an A record.

Comment: its already pointing but i need to mask destination domain .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To masking, the domains must be in the same server. In the Apache configuration, the alias of your first domain must have the other domain. In some hosting panels, this options appears as "Parking Domains"

Comment: is it compulsory to be in a same server . Is their no other way of doing it ? proxy php or something else ?